# Obfuscate Android bytecode

Tags: android, proguard, obfuscation

All,
    I'm trying to use proguard to obfuscate .APK file and it seems not working. As Proguard mainly works for Java bytecode, I use dex2jar to convert the apk file to jar file, use Proguard to obfuscate it, and then repackage the output jar into apk. The resulting apk seems problematic. I got a lot of error like `Could not read file: Expected chunk of type 0x80003, read 0x6d783f3c`.  Is there anyway that I can obfuscate the Android bytecode directly on .apk instead of source code? Please help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use proguard with the proper configuration for android.
There is also a predefined setting for your gradle build file (when using android studio)

```
android {
 ... 
 buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),
        'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
  }
}
```

Source: http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html

Comment: The question I'm asking is to obfuscate the .apk file. Clearly this is the configuration for source code.

Comment: So you can't just build it with this option but want to obfuscate an already existing apk? Did you resign the apk before testing it?

Comment: I want to obfuscate already existing apks (written by others) to test some program analysis techniques

Comment: Did you resign the apk after changing it? And did you use the proguard configuration for android?